# Read binary data from a binary file

Tags: c++

I am writing a structure into a file using the following line:

```c++
std::fstream snif::fileHandler;
fileHandler.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(rawData), sizeof(rawDataStruct));
```

where `rawdataStruct` is:

```c++
typedef struct _rawData rawDataStruct;
```

now after writing the structures into the file, I am reading the structure from the beginning of the binary file using:

```c++
std::cout << "going for print data read from file\n";
snif::fileHandler.seekg(0); //, std::ios::beg);
snif::fileHandler.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(rawData), sizeof(rawDataStruct));

if (snif::fileHandler.fail()) {
    std::cerr << "reading error\n";
    exit(0);
}

std::cout << "PSH flag = " << rawData->tcpFlag.PSH << std::endl
          << "source port " << rawData->sourcePort << std::endl
          << "destination port " << rawData->destinationPort << std::endl
          << " sequence number " << rawData->sequenceNumber << std::endl
          << " Acknowledge number " << rawData->acknowledgeNumber << std::endl
          << " acknowledge flag " << rawData->tcpFlag.ACK << std::endl
          << " SYN flag      " << rawData->tcpFlag.SYN << std::endl
          << "FIN flag      " << rawData->tcpFlag.FIN << std::endl;
```

but if I check my standard output, the last line geting printed is:

```c++
"going for print data read from file";
```

Comment: Did you check if `snif::fileHandler` is good to read from (using e.g. `.fail()`) before reading? If the open has failed, I'm guessing your program is trying to read from stdin (file descriptor 0).

Answer (score 0):

There is no code showing it, but what mode is the file opened?  Hopefully it is configured for `binary`.  To see the available options, review [`std::basic_fstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) and [`std::ios_base::openmode`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode).  I suggest to make sure that the following open modes are set:

```
ios::binary | ios::out | ios::in | ios::trunc
```

Depending on what purpose is happening, `ios::trunc` (truncate) may have to be replaced by `ios::app` (append).

While doing some basic testing, it has been discovered on my C++11 compliant compiler that the

```
fileHandler.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(rawData), sizeof(rawDataStruct));
```

has a potential problem that is easily solved by adding the `&` operator in front of the rawData like this:

```
fileHandler.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&rawData), sizeof(rawDataStruct));
```

The compiler should have given a warning, but that is contingent on the compiler version, and whether the `-Wall` option or better is used.  This may explain how the screen output seemingly stops at the

```
"going for print data read from file"
```

message.  The read function also needs the `&` operator in front of rawData:

```
snif::fileHandler.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&rawData), sizeof(rawDataStruct));
```

Perhaps a run-time exception from the `reinterpret_cast<>` operator is being thrown that is not being caught.  It is difficult to know until the system and compiler are documented.

Additionally, if `rawData` is declared as a pointer, then a better variable name is `pRawData`, as well as posting more of the code.  For example, if the `pRawData` is never pointing to a valid instance of the `rawDataStruct`, then unpredictable things will occur.

Comment: forget about open, after writing data into file, if I do fileHandler.close(); after that line nothing is printed by std::out

Comment: @Startup Well the file needs to be opened for data to be written.

Comment: @0x499602D2 sorry i dod not provide that code hear, by I opened my file, and if i check the size of file, it's increasing due to writing.

Comment: @Startup See the modification regarding the `&` operator in front of `rawData`.